# How to make custom exception in http unit test?

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing, laravel-exceptions

On laravel  site in controller I catch custom KeyIsNotProvidedException Exception:

```
<?php
        try {
            $data = $this->method();
            ...
        } catch (KeyIsNotProvidedException $e) {

            return response()->json([
                'code' => 500,
                'message' => 'Check if valid Key is Provided',
            ], JsonResponse::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // 500
        } catch (\Error | \Exception $e) {

            return response()->json([
                'error_message' => $e->getMessage(),
            ], JsonResponse::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // 500
        }
```

Also Making test for this controller when custom error is raised I wonder which class have I to use here:

```
...
$this->withoutExceptionHandling();
$this->expectException(WhichClassMustBeUsedHere::class); // ???
...

$this
    ->post(route('items.action'), [
    ]);
```

Also as in the controller I return 500 code, which best practice can be used here for controller and for test?

```
   "laravel/framework": "^10.8",
   "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expect the Exception:

```
$this->expectException(KeyIsNotProvidedException::class)
```

To assert against the 500 status

```
$this->post(route('items.action'), [])->assertServerError();
```

Comment: As I catch KeyIsNotProvidedException in my controller, but it is not returned from controller action,
do I need to use in expectException other class? Which ?

Looks like $response->assertServerError() works ok, but can I conbine it with expectException method ?

Comment: `$this->withoutExceptionhandling()` sets up a new default exception handler.  Therefore it will only respond to uncaught exceptions.   If your plan is to manually emit a 500 server error I would just use `assertServerError()` and not worry about the exception